# Make Jenkins show dashboard without account

Tags: jenkins, dashboard

I would like anyone to go to the server's home page and just see the dashboard—without having an account or logging in. They would have to log in if they wanted to see/do anything else.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible use some plugin based on Matrix Authorization Strategy for example [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin). Then add read permission for Anonymous Users.